# If we run a Celery worker with concurrency as 1 does pool option matter?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Since we are running the celery worker with -concurrency as 1, Does setting the -pool as prefork or eventlet matter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Even when concurrency is set to 1, there are still consequences for the choice of pool. The availability/behavior of certain remote commands and settings is, in part, dictated by your choice of pool. For example, [max-tasks-per-child](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting) is only available with the `prefork` pool.

Among other potential impacts, it also has an impact on how your tasks behave at runtime. Some libraries are completely incompatible with eventlet, for example.